# Really confused on how to extract a value from an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

So basically I have this if statement:

```
int md; // md = marriage deduction
    if (married == 'M'){
    md = 750;
    System.out.println("Deduction for Being Married: " + md);
    }
    else if (married == 'S'){
    md = 500;
    System.out.println("Deduction for Being Single: " + md);
    }
```

And I'm really confused about how to basically extract the value of md from that if statement. I have to, right after this if statement, calculate another integer based on the value of md, but when I try to do so, md is undefined and shows up as an error. Like this:

```
int total = balance - md - ad
```

Balance and ad work fine because I didn't have to use if statements for them, but md won't have a value. The error says that it's undefined which I get because I never initialized it outside of the if statement, I'm just wondering how to get the value of md out of the if statements. Thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`md` is undefined because when you declare it, you don't set its value. If `married` is not `M` or `S`, then `md` goes undefined. Otherwise, `md` should retain whatever value you assign it because it is outside of the `if` statement's scope.

Just add an `else` clause to set `md` to zero:

```
if (married == 'M')
{
    md = 750;
    System.out.println("Deduction for Being Married: " + md);
}
else if (married == 'S')
{
    md = 500;
    System.out.println("Deduction for Being Single: " + md);
}
else
{
    md = 0;
    // TODO: System.out.println("Oops. You are neither married nor single.");
}
```

Alternatively, you could just initialize your `md` to zero. I recommend doing both:

```
int md = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot. I've been writing this code for a while and this is pretty much the first time I got stuck. Thanks a lot to everyone who answered, except the people who just said "that's wrong herp derp".

Answer (score 2):

I would add an adendum to these answers.

```
if (married == 'M') {
    md = 750;
    System.out.println("Deduction for Being Married: " + md);
} else if (married == 'S') {
    md = 500;
    System.out.println("Deduction for Being Single: " + md);
} else {
    md = 0;
    // what if we later add functionality to add divorced or widowed?
    // would this really be the desired functionality to set md to 0
    // better to throw an exception saying we don't recognise the value of married
    // eg. 
    throw new IllegalStateException("unrecognised married state: "+married);
}
```

Alternatively you might want to explore using enums

```
public enum Married {

    M("married", 750),
    S("single", 500);

    private String name;
    private int points;

    Married(String name, int points) {
        this.name = name;
        this.points = points;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getPoints() { return points; }

}

String input = // get input somehow

Married status = Married.valueOf(input);
// status is either M or S now. It cannot be null as valueOf throws an exception if it 
// cannot match the input to string to any of the possible values of the enum

int total = balance - status.getPoints() - ad;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your value for married is almost certainly not M or S, thus you're hitting neither branch of your statement and md is never being defined.

Comment: that's wrong sorry because earlier i set it so that unless the user inputs M or S for married the program ends, i got the answer already though so thanks for trying.

Comment: I think you're probably wrong, seeing as the answer you picked also only fixes the case when `married` is neither `'M'` nor `'S'`. Regardless, I would do a little research on definition vs. declaration to avoid issues like this in the future. As @Justin mentions, you're declaring `md`, but never actually defining it.

Comment: Robotica is right. Whilst you might know that it is impossible for the else branch to be executed the compiler is not so bright. It does a simple analysis of the if branch and detects that there is a possibility that md might not be initialised. It does not backtrace up your code to examine whether this would ever be the case.

Answer (score 1):

if married isn't 'M' or 'S', then md will be undefined.

Comment: orly? I know, it's supposed to be that. If it isn't M or S the program ends, that's in a waayyy earlier part of the code though.

Answer (score 1):

You have a condition where `married` is neither `S` nor `M`... so add a final `else` to set it to zero.

```
if (married == 'M'){
md = 750;
System.out.println("Deduction for Being Married: " + md);
}
else if (married == 'S'){
md = 500;
System.out.println("Deduction for Being Single: " + md);
}
else {
md = 0;
}
```

Or do it before the entire if statement...

Or you have lower case `s` or `m` which fails a case sensitive condition

Comment: thank you i got it from someone else already but thanks for helping out

Comment: @user789753: it's customary to look at the time stamp of answers to see who answered correctly *first*.. then accept/upvote

Comment: That's what I did... Justin Satyr gave me almost an identical answer to yours which solved my problem, 1 minute before you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is JAVA we are talking about and **married** is a String object You should compare them by using .equalsTo:

```
if (married.equalsTo("M")) {...
```

Comment: It appears as though `married` is not a `String` object but a primitive `char`, as indicated by OP's choice of single quotes around `M`.  Also FYI the language is called "Java" and not "JAVA"...it's an exciting language, but not so exciting that we shout it's name :)